# How to apply a fadeIn effect when adding rows to a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am currently adding rows to a table using the .insertAfter() funciton within my document.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            CheckRowLength();
            $("#add").click(function () {
                $('#querytable tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#querytable tr:last');
                $('#querytable tr:last #name').val('');
                CheckRowLength();
                return false;
            });

            $("#del").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                CheckRowLength();
            });
            function CheckRowLength() {
                var RowCount = $('#querytable tr').length;
                if (RowCount > 2) {
                    $('#querytable tr:last #del').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('#del').hide();
                }
            }
        });
```

html markup

```
<table id="querytable">

            <tr>
                <td id="col1">
                    Field Name
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a id="add">Add</a>
                    <a id="del">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
```

The effect I would like to obtain is when the row is added have it fade in. I tried to use the fadeIn() function but I am not implementing it correctly as nothing is happening.

```
$('#querytable tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#querytable tr:last').fadeIn('slow');
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction for this effect. Or is this even possible when used in conjunction with insertAfter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include some sample markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the contents of your `<td>`'s with a `<div>`, which you then apply the fade effects to.  Here's a blog post I wrote recently where I was doing the same thing with slide instead of fade:
http://duncan99.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/using-jquery-to-animate-table-rows/

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding the div tags

Comment: Please don't wrap your <td> with a <div> tag... that is not syntactically correct and you will be lucky if it renders correctly in all browsers.

Comment: I meant wrap the content of the <td> with a <div>, not wrap a <div> around the <td>

Answer (score 1):

Without your markup I can't be positive, but I'm guessing you need to hide it before adding it,

```
$('#querytable tr:last').clone(true).hide().insertAfter('#querytable tr:last').fadeIn('slow');
```

Changing the opacity from 1 to .. 1 isn't expected to show anything.

Answer (score 1):

The element needs to be hidden before you can fade it in. Try something like this:

```
elem = $('#querytable tr:last').clone(true);
elem.css('display', 'none');
elem.insertAfter('#querytable tr:last');
elem.fadeIn('fast')
```

It would probably look better if you used the slideDown() or slideUp() effect.

Answer (score 0):

while inserting the table rows , they should already be hidden , ... so basically , insert `<tr> with style= " display:none"` , and then apply the `fadeIn()` effect.

the deal is , that you can not fade in something that is already visible.